# Winforms control that indicates if single process is running

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I'm working on a winforms app with an embedded vpn.  I would like to have a control indicate vpn connection status by indicating whether or not the vpn process is running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Timer control that periodically fires off a BackgroundWorker component to check the VPN connection status. I do this to check network connection status and toggle the enabled state of a button. It's also necessary to check status when the button is clicked in case the connection is dropped between polls.

Comment: Jamie, Thanks for your help!

-s